# SSIS apparently changes data type of column in inbound Excel file

Tags: excel, types, ssis

I have an Excel file coming in from an outside vendor.  Column A contains a unique identifier that usually starts with the letter "K" but the first several records start with a number "9", so of course SSIS wants to interpret the column as numeric, causing the "K" records to come out of the Excel data source as null.  So I set the column data type to WSTR(20) in Advanced Editor, which worked fine in development.  But when I run from the prod environment and my inbound file has the first several records starting with "9", SSIS seems to dynamically change the data type to numeric and then the "K" records again come out as null.  I realize that putting the "K" records first will solve the problem but I have no control over a file from an outside vendor.  Your suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not SSIS, it's what the excel driver is reporting to SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS guesses the data types based on a sample of the first X rows in the file.  You can expand the range of sampling but it is limited.  You can always go in and override/manually set the data type for the column in the Advanced Editor for the source.  Setting it manually base on pre-existing knowledge will always give you the best results.

Answer (score 0):

In ssis we can increase default guess rows by changing connection configuration used to connect excel file. You can set IMEX=1 in connection string to increase type guess rows.